# Integral of $\int \sin^{-1} \left (e^{\sqrt x}\right )\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I evaluate the following;

$$\displaystyle \int \sin^{-1} \left (e^{\sqrt x}\right ) \mathrm{d}x$$

$$\displaystyle \int \sin^{-1} \left (e^{-\sqrt x} \right )\mathrm{d}x$$

Is there a closed form? How do I solve for it?

No substitution seems to work.

Comment: I have found a solution with mathematica, it's very long and I cant show you workings since mathematica dosen't provide me any, but I can show you a solution, is this of interest, or is the interest in the path to finding the solution.

Comment: Do you mean result? Does it involve hypergeometric functions? The interest is both in the result and the solution.

Comment: Yes, it does involve hypergeometric functions

Comment: Does it look impossible to evaluate?

Comment: The second one seems reasonable, [screenshot of solution](http://i.imgur.com/r3NHXIT.png)

Comment: See the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) and [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)).

Comment: @Lucian So, according to Liouville's theorem, this $\color{red}{\textrm{CAN'T}}$ have an elementary antiderivative(unless there are some series representations I'm missing). Interesting. So what do we do in such cases? Simplify the expression untill a CAS can find the result?

Comment: You can, of course, express $\arcsin$ as an infinite series, and then switch the order of summation and integration. But substituting won't solve anything.

Comment: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=arcsin%28e%5E%28x%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29&random=false